# Rails thread-safe including module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thread-safety

I would like to include module in my Application Controller based on instance variable.

I've got something like this right now:

```
class ApplicationController

  before_filter :include_module

  def include_module
    @@site = "foo"
    class_eval{ include @@site.classify.constantize::Bar }
  end
end
```

However, I would like to make this snippet thread safe. Is it possible? What I would like to achieve, is on each request load module, which name depends on some variable.

Comment: So for every single request you're going to load/evaluate a module?

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea, is there a better way to do what you want?

Comment: yep, I also think, that each time I use class_eval god kills one kitten, but here's what I want to do:

Comment: yep, I also think, that each time I use class_eval god kills one kitten, but here's what I want to do: Imagine that one rails app handles many pages, which shares some codebase, but a lot of them are different. This is why I came up with idea of "controller parts" – idea is to have default actions in controllers, but custom, for some sites(subdomains) will be loaded from controller part and exectued, so code for given action will be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK Rails is thread safe and on MRI will be single threaded. However context matters. Are you running MRI or JRuby? I suggest you read through the following 3 once

http://m.onkey.org/thread-safety-for-your-rails

http://yehudakatz.com/2010/08/14/threads-in-ruby-enough-already/

http://blog.headius.com/2008/08/qa-what-thread-safe-rails-means.html

EDIT: If your rails application is single threaded then your variables are thread safe. I should have added that before. In that context Rails is thread safe.

Comment: Although to the OS MRI is single threaded, to your program it looks like the scary world of race conditions and semaphores. Beware.

Comment: @Linuxios, I am not sure of that. can you give some example? I am running quite complex large systems using ruby and have made the single threaded assumption and faced no race conditions. What kind of race conditions are you talking about?

Comment: @av: Starting with Ruby MRI 1.9, Ruby uses real OS threads (pthreads on UNIX) for each Ruby thread, **BUT**, Ruby will only be executing *Ruby* code in one thread at a time. So while one OS thread can be waiting on IO, or executing plain C, it can't be executing Ruby. Also, because Ruby threads are scheduled preemptively, which means that one of your code statements can be preempted in the middle of execution, leaving variables in undefined state, or in the middle of a critical section. Because of that, you need to lock your variables with mutexes when every you have multiple Ruby threads.

Comment: @av: Think of a program with 2 threads that all increment the global variable `$c`. Each contains this: `10000.times {$c += 1}`. So, first thread one get's to execute the *addition* of `$c+1`, but **NOT** the assignment. Then thread 2 gets through the addition and assignment, leaving `$c` at `1` (it started as 0). Now, we go back to thread one, who does the assignment of 1 to `$c`. So now we've had two `+=`s, but we've only added *one* to `$c`, not 2. This is the classic race condition. It gets even worse on a truly multithreaded implementation like JRuby, where

Comment: @av: The threads can be accessing the variable *at the same time* (on a multiprocessor system), or very close (on a single core system). Then you might get the upper half bits from one addition, and the lower half from the other. Whenever two threads access a shared resource, you MUST lock it with a mutex, semaphore, or other access control mechanism.

Comment: @Linuxios, the problem you are talking about is global variables. With global variables any program needs to be careful. Unless you really need them [there are situations where you cannot avoid them], don't use them. We have huge system running fine with very few global variables. If you ruby without global variables then you need worry one bit. We have a fairly large and complex system consisting of sinatra apps, rails apps and event machine based apps all running fine without a single mutex as we do not have global variables. If you do, one mustprotect them, but it is not scary or difficult.

Comment: @Linuxios So considering the original question, the default class variables and local variables are all thread safe because ruby is single threaded with the MRI.

Comment: @av: I don't use them, but the point is that threads need to communicate. There are many other ways that threads can mess up each others data, and globals are just one. The point is, if threads communicate, they need syncronisation.

Comment: @av: Not exactly. Thread local variables can be accessed from any thread, and class variables are shared between subclasses and superclasses, and class objects are global.

Comment: @Linuxios, I agree, if threads share data you should protect them. However from a rails perspective what the original question was requesting is thread safe. I was coming from a perspective that if I have a single threaded rails application, then that data is completely thread safe because for each rails request is going to run through sequentially. If I throw threads of my own and share data between them then I have to protect that data. So I guess I did not make that part clear in my answer.

Comment: Well for starters using class variables like that isn't thread safe - a second request could easily come along and change @@site before the call to class_eval

Comment: @FrederickCheung This second request will be serialized. Rails will not process two in parallel, right? Try putting a sleep in the controller and make one request and while this request is sleeping make another from another tab in the browser. It will not go through until the first one completes.

Comment: @av501: Agreed. Sorry about the misunderstanding, but that was interesting. But about your last comment: Ruby can preempt a thread in the middle of an statement. That means that another thread can always be run while your assignment is just almost done, but freeze dried on the shelf.

Comment: Av501: depends entirely on your setup. config.thread_safe is off by default but will be on in rails 4 by default apparently.